# Remove folder remotely but not locally git

Tags: git, gitlab

A contributor in a git repo (on gitlab) pushed his `.metadata` folder.
I know added it to `.gitignore`. How can I know achieve, that this `.metadata` folder is deleted on the repo (as well as on my local), but is not deleted on my collaborators local copy?

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution I can think of is, you can delete the folder locally and include it in gitignore. Then push the changes to remote. From there everyone else can pull. Now you can restore the .metadata folder in local and avoid pushing it to remote from now on.